# Redirect all calls to alias to one page in sub folder on same alias

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wamp, http-redirect

I have a problem with creating htaccess file on wamp sever.
I want to all calls to the alias (virtual folder) on  localhost server redirect to public folder on same alias.
For example i want to

```
http://localhost/test/***/ or http://localhost/test/***/***/***/
```

redirect to

```
http://localhost/test/public/indes.php?a=******.
```

I found a lot of examples but no one does not work correctly, I getting an error "The page isn't redirecting properly" or "500 Internal Server Error".

This is my htaccess example file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/test/public/index.php [R=301,L]
```

Can someone please tell me where I'm wrong?
Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: Same again "The page isn't redirecting properly" in Firefox or "This webpage has a redirect loop" in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give it a try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/public/index.php
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Santy, you saved me! 
I would only add one more thing to complete answer. 
Instead of the last line 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/public/index.php, I'd put 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/public/index.php?a=$1. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well yeh, you could but you could also use it to make "friendly urls" like yourdomain.com/account/manager/ and fetch what the url is with in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] instead of yourdomain.com/?action=account&section=manager ... etc.